# Image processing in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

I am opening a 3.5 MB file in C reading it into an unsigned char array Image data which I have initialized as follows:

```
unsigned char *** Imagedata;
Imagedata = new unsigned char**[1278];
for(int i=0; i<1278; i++){
    Imagedata[i]= new unsigned char*[968];
    for(int j=0; j<968; j++){
        Imagedata[i][j]= new unsigned char[3];
    }
}
```

Now i open the file and read it into the array as:

```
ifstream ifile;
ifile.open("abcde.raw", ios::in|ios::binary);
for(int i=0; i<1278; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<968; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
            ifile>>Imagedata[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}
ifile.close();
```

The next step is to just rewrite the bytes into a new file.. which i call rawfile.. I have tried to achieve it like this:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("rawfile.raw", ios::out|ios::binary);
for(int i=0; i<1278; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<968; j++){
        myfile.write((char *)Imagedata[i][j],3*sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
}
myfile.close();
```

It somehow doesn seem to work.. the image file that i get is garbage.. what could be the problem?

Comment: You know, of course, that you should use `const` variables or `#defines` instead of the literal numbers `1278` and `968`.

Comment: Yeah I usually do that.. its just for this sample code.. Thanks for mentioning it anyways..

Comment: Always worthwhile pointing it out to any newbies who happen to read it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ifile>>Imagedata[i][j][k];
```

This is formatted input, it eats 'whitespace' characters even though you specified `ios::binary`. Use

```
Imagedata[i][j][k] = ifile.get();
```

Even better, allocate one big chunk of memory for the whole file and read it by one `read` call. What you do now is allocating a pointer for each pixel, which is very wasteful especially for 64-bit systems.

Comment: Thanks! this works.. also.. i found another way that worked.. i removed the third looping during the reading..
    for(int i=0; i<1278; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<968; j++){
                ifile.read((char*)Imagedata[i][j],3);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would bet this is because the skipws flag is set by default in file streams. Right after opening your fstreams, add file.unsetf( std::ios_base::skipws );

Comment: Would that be set even for a binary stream? That seems silly.

Comment: Yes, it does. I am not aware of the rationale, but has bitten me many times.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell if it needs fixing, without knowing the rationale for it.