# Image processing in C++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I want to read a raw file, which has 3 interleaving and has a size of about(3.5MB) large into a three dimensional array.. the code that I am using to read the file is:

```
ifile.open(argv[2], ios::in|ios::binary);
for(int i=0; i<1278; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<968; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
            Imagedata1[i][j][k]=ifile.get();
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is this array is not what i expect it to be.. I need the 1278 to be the width of the image.. the 968 to be the height and 3 bytes are the RGB values.. how should i write the code to read from the file such that the array gets populated correctly.. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to give a small explanation of how you going to use this data.

Comment: and please dont mind the numerical values.. will use #define or const later in the code :)

Comment: What's the type of `Imagedata1`? Does the file consist of RGB triples in ascii? If not, how are they encoded?

Comment: will use the array indices to target specific bits of the image file.. and manipulate them into changing color of a specific region..

Comment: Imagedata1 is unsigned char ***.. the array is dynamically allocated.. using new char**[1278] and then in a loop new char*[968] and then new char[3].. the file is a raw file.. no encoding..

Comment: I don't fully understand what's the problem. but mind that, the file may have a 4D picture (alpha channel). you should check that.

Comment: @PROC_HANDLER - That's a *really* inefficient way to lay out your array.

Comment: what would you suggest?? @Omnifarious
Roee Gavirel No.. its not a 4D.. its a 2d picture.. with 3 bytes per color of RGB.. the idea is to access the bits as rows and columns.. like a matrix.. will make my job that much easier..

Comment: I gave my suggestion in my answer. The suggestion I gave allocates all of the memory all at once. This is much more cache friendly, and also saves on levels of indirection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image processing in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374337/image-processing-in-c)

Comment: @Paul R no.. it was a diff question.. i had asked for a way to allocate large chunk of memory..

Comment: @PROC_HACKER: the previous question also covers reading the file too, so I still maintain that this is a duplicate. Please go back and improve the original question rather than posting a modified version of the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, image files are usually stored, in order of smallest jump to largest, color values, column, row order. You are not reading them in that order.

```
ifile.open(argv[2], ios::in|ios::binary);
for(int j=0; j<968; j++){
    for(int i=0; i<1278; i++){
        for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
            Imagedata1[i][j][k]=ifile.get();
        }
    }
}
```

That is how the loop should be arranged, though you may want to rename your variables to keep things straight:

```
ifile.open(argv[2], ios::in|ios::binary);
for(int row=0; row<968; row++){
    for(int col=0; col<1278; col++){
        for(int color=0; color<3; color++){
            Imagedata1[col][row][color]=ifile.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, the way you allocate your array is really broken and inefficient. Here is how it should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class ColorValue {
 public:
   ColorValue(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
     : r_(r), g_(g), b_(b) {}
   ColorValue() : r_(0), g_(0), b_(0) {}

   unsigned char getR() const { return r_; }
   unsigned char getG() const { return g_; }
   unsigned char getB() const { return b_; }

 private:
   unsigned char r_, g_, b_;
};

void readrows(const char *fname, ColorValue imagedata[][1278])
{
   ::std::ifstream ifile;
   ifile.open(fname, ::std::ios::in|::std::ios::binary);
   for (int row = 0; row < 968; ++row) {
      for (int col = 0; col < 1278; ++col) {
         char r, g, b;
         ifile.get(r);
         ifile.get(g);
         ifile.get(b);
         imagedata[row][col] = ColorValue(r, g, b);
      }
   }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   ColorValue (*imagedata)[1278] = new ColorValue[968][1278];
   readrows(argv[1], imagedata);
   delete[] imagedata;
}
```

Using a class for `ColorValue` keeps you from having magic indexes everywhere in your code for the 'r', 'g', and 'b' components. And allocating the array in this way keeps all the memory used for the image contiguous and removes several levels of unnecessary indirection. These both have the property of making your program much more cache friendly.

I also found [a nice article that's a really comprehensive treatment of multi-dimensional arrays in C++](http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1040/2008/4/deleting-multidimensional-array-pointers.htm).

Comment: Hi @Omnifarious.. thank you for your suggestions.. Why have you used typedef ColorValue imagerow_t[1278] ?

Comment: @PROC_HACKER - Because that's the only way I could figure out to declare `imagedata` as a pointer to a multidimensional array. I didn't want to declare a pointer to an array of pointers, I wanted to declare a pointer to an array of arrays. The typedef technique let me do that. It's possible there's a way to declare `imagedata` without relying on the typedef.

Comment: @PROC_HACKER - After further experimenting, you can declare `imagedata` this way: `ColorValue (*imagedata)[1278] = new ColorValue[968][1278];`. As you see, you have to use parenthesis to make the binding work so you aren't declaring an array of pointers, but instead declaring a pointer to an array of arrays.

Comment: @PROC_HACKER - I will edit this to remove the typedef. I think that will make it a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I will look it up and try to get a better understanding.. Am trying to stick with your code for now.. lets see if i can get it to work for my case.. really appreciate all the help..

Answer (score 0):

C arrays don't work like that.

Let's say you wanted a 2D 1024*768 pixel buffer, with 4 bytes per pixel.  You'd do something like this:

```
  unsigned int pixbuf[1024*768];

  for (int irow=0; irow < 1024; irow++)
    for (int icol=0; icol < 768; icol++)
      pixbuf[(irow*1024)+icol] = icolor;
```

Here is a good link that explains further:

http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9.html

'Hope that helps!

Comment: what you are doing here is just what the compiler will do anyway. cause you can define "unsigned char pixbuf[1024][768];"

Comment: Even though its not what i am looking for.. i think with a little bit of arithmetic in mind i will be able to make it work.. I am really looking for a better way though.. there has to be some way in which we can get it in a 3d array.. and then just iterate over it..

Answer (score 0):

As long as you always access your data through the three-dimensional array it does not matter how the structure of the array is laid down in memory. In your example you define the first index (i) as the column index, the (j) index as the row index and the (k) index as the pixel component index.

I suspect your image file has the data organized in the standard way, which is an array of rows, where each row is an array of pixels, where each pixel is an array of color components. If that is the case, then you can modify your code to work with that structure:

```
ifile.open(argv[2], ios::in|ios::binary);
for(int i=0; i<1278; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<968; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
            Imagedata1[j][i][k]=ifile.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I just swapped the i and j indexes in the body of the innermost for loop, the rest of the code is identical to yours.

If you also need to access the image data as a planar buffer, then you should reorganize your arrays so that the data in memory mimics the layout from the file. For this you want the first dimension to be the rows, then columns, then color components. That would end up like this:

```
unsigned char Imagedata1[968][1278][3];

ifile.open(argv[2], ios::in|ios::binary);
for(int i=0; i<968; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<1278; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
            Imagedata1[i][j][k]=ifile.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Update: after a quick discussion in the comments, it seems you do want to read this in a more efficient way. If you want to load this image on the stack (probably not a good idea) you would declare your image buffer as:

```
unsigned char Imagedata1[968][1278][3];
```

I would instead put it on the heap, like this:

```
unsigned char* Imagedata1 = new unsigned char[968*1278*3];
```

Then you can read the data from the file with:

```
if (fread(Imagedata1, 1278*3, 968, fd) != 968) {
    // handle error here
}
```

Note that the numbers that you put as count and size in the fread call are not that important, as long as those two numbers multiplied are equal to width*height*components.

If you then need to access this image as a 3-dimensional array, I recommend that you create an auxiliary function, something like this:

```
unsigned char* getPixel(int col, int row)
{
    return Imagedata1 + row * 1278 * 3 + col * 3;
}
```

The return value of this function can be used as a one dimensional array of three elements, the red, green and blue of the pixel.

As a final suggestion, I recommend that you wrap your image in a class, and add member variables that define the width and height (and maybe the number of color planes as well). You do not want to hardcode the 1278s and the 968s all over the place in your code!

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Miguel.. Thank you for the reply.. But i have tried that too.. and it doesn seem to work for me.. I will tell you what I am actually trying to achieve here.. This large picture is a background image over which I need to insert another image.. the foreground image is smaller in size (around 300x300x3).. so its being easily manipulated by just declaring a three dimensional array and then using fread like this.. 
    fread(imagedata, 1, 300x300x3, file);
this copies the image file exactly the way i want it in terms of rows and columns.. but if i try to do the same with the larger file.. i get

Comment: a segmentation fault.. then doing it by dynamically allocation of memory.. it works.. but I am not able to get the values as rows and columns.. as in 1250x600 should be somewhere on the bottom right corner.. but it turns out.. its not..

Comment: Is the size of your large image exactly 3,711,312 bytes? That's what you will get if you fread the whole thing. You may want to add details regarding the seg fault.

Comment: yeah the size is exactly that.. funny thing is the details for the seg fault dont come up in the debugger.. but when i comment out the fread then the code runs.. so i am thinking thats the problem..

Comment: You need to show more of your code. The definition of Imagedata1 and the way you read using fread.

Comment: okay.. here it is..
    unsigned char *** Imagedata;
    Imagedata = new unsigned char**[1278];
    for(int i=0; i< 1278; i ++){
        Imagedata[i] = new char*[968];
        for(int j=0; j<968; j++){
            Imagedata[i][j] = new char[3];
        }
     }

FILE* file;
file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
fread(Imagedata,sizeof(unsigned char), 1278*968*3, file);
file.close